# Set Azure Batch MaxWallClockTime Node SDK

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I'm trying to set a `maxWallClockTime` of 72 hours using the ISO 8601 Duration format. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/batch/taskconstraints?view=azure-node-latest#maxWallClockTime) for this property is useless, so I'm basing my guess on using the 8601 format on that being the way to set the same property at the [Batch Job level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/batch/job?view=azure-cli-latest#az_batch_job_create-optional-parameters) when using the CLI. My constraints object is as follows:

```
const taskConstraints = {
   maxWallClockTime: 'P3D' //ISO 8601 Duration Format e.g. P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S represents a duration of three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds.
};
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
task.constraints.maxWallClockTime must be a TimeSpan/Duration.
```

I cannot find any examples that set this property and use the Javascript API, any pointers to better documentation or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to specify it in `3.00:00:00` format? Something like `const taskConstraints = {
   maxWallClockTime: '3.00:00:00' 
};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed the docs are lacking here. I haven't tested this out locally yet, but from looking at the code I believe the answer depends on whether you are using the older Node.js-specific [azure-batch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-batch) package or the newer [@azure/batch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/batch) which also runs in web browsers.

For the "azure-batch" package, it looks like it takes a Moment.js duration object. Here's the related JSDoc string:

```
 * @property {moment.duration} [maxWallClockTime] The maximum elapsed time
 * that the Task may run, measured from the time the Task starts. If the Task
 * does not complete within the time limit, the Batch service terminates it.
 * If this is not specified, there is no time limit on how long the Task may
 * run.
```

For the newer "@azure/batch" package, it should take an ISO-8601 duration string. If you're using that package then the value you're trying to use looks right to me, and maybe it's a bug (I'd have to try to repro it).